# How to show an image for a specific time period?

Tags: android

In my application i need to decrypt the certain message format, to extract information like message id, timeout and so on.i need to show an corresponding image for the given id as well as to show it for the mentioned time period. 
For that i have created one custom layout to show the image and other details. i'm using imageview for displaying the image. but dont know how to set timeiut for that?
Do anyone have idea on that?

Comment: You can format your question well that it can be easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use `Handler` to do that, like this

```
                imageuser.setImageBitmap(bitmapObject);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imageuser.setImageBitmap(null);
                    }
                }, 5000);
```

here, `imageuser` is your `ImageView` and replace `5000` with your specific time in miliseconds.

Comment: what's the point of an ImageView if you use setBackgroundResource ?

Comment: @njzk2 The user wants to know how to show the image for specific time, he already know how to set image into imageview so that's the priority and that's what I demonstrated now he can use any other method of imageview also. What you say?

Comment: i'm just saying, using the background attiribute of an imageview is a common misconception, which i try to point out any chance i get. (it doesn't, indeed, changes the fact that the answer is correct)

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like whenever you want to show image just call your UI and start a thread for the given time you want to show the image and when the time complete just make that ui visibility gone,this is the logic try it in your own way.
thanks

Comment: thanks.. but how can i specify timeout while creating an activity?